# jQuery get the next sibling hidden value on click

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the hidden field value on click event of a link. Here's where those elements are:

```
<p>
    <a class="showCommentAttachment cboxElement" href="#">Attachments</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="13" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lvComment_ctrl3_hfCommentId" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lvComment$ctrl3$hfCommentId">
</p>
```

Here the complete mark-up:

```
<div id="divComment" class="comment-text">
    <div class="comment-author">
         David Chart
    </div>
    <span class="comment-date-time">Sep 29, 2011 08:12:42 PM</span>
    <p>
         Some comment text goes here. Some comment text goes here.

    </p>
    <p>
        <a class="showCommentAttachment cboxElement" href="#">Attachments</a>
        <input type="hidden" value="13" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lvComment_ctrl3_hfCommentId" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lvComment$ctrl3$hfCommentId">
    </p>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$("#divComment a.showCommentAttachment").click(function() {

    var nextSibling = $(this).next().find('input:hidden').val();

    $("#showCommentId").html(nextSibling + "<-- Here's the comment ID ");

 });
```

what I get back from nextSibling is undefined. I tried with nexAll like this

> var nextSibling = $(this).nextAll().find('input:hidden').val();

still got undefined.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use simply `$(this).next()` since the next element is surely the hidden input field. Also with `$(this).next().find()` you are querying the children elements of the hidden input element. This is from [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

> **.find()**
>
> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

So you need `$(this).next().val()`.

Answer (score 3):

`.next()` gives you the next sibling which is the input field itself. Calling `.find()` is then searching for descendants of this field (there aren't any).

You just want `$(this).next().val()`

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
$(this).next().val();
```

or

```
$("#divComment a.showCommentAttachment").next().val();
```